# SAP Cloud Application Programming Model CAP: Display Message Toast

Tags: toast, sap-fiori

Using SAP Cloud Application Programming Model ([CAP](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/)), in a Node.js application with Fiori Elements like the [bookshop sample](https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-cap-samples/tree/master/bookshop),
how can I display a [Message Toast](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/message-toast/)
to indicate that an action completed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Using the request object `req` passed to the event handler:

`req.notify("Your success message goes here!");`

See also: https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/node.js/requests#req-msg

Ideally, the message should be translated a.k.a. localized.

See also: https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/node.js/app-services#i18n

Answer (score 0):

The part you are referring to is the backend. I'm not sure if you can trigger Toast Messages from backend. But you need to catch the message and display it at the frontend part of your application by using the MessageToast object.

https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/node.js/requests#req-msg This seems like a suggestion of in which way you "typically" handle the message.

You need to check severity of the message that is returned from the backend (http request) and use MessageToast.show or MessageBox.error or MessageBox.warning etc.